# What properties does a Markov chain formed from a Poisson process modulo m have?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, poisson-process

Let $N(t)$ be a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$. Suppose that we wanted to construct a continuous-time Markov chain with a finite state space $S$ by setting $X_t = N(t) \text{ (mod } n\text{)}, n \in \mathbb{N}, \left| S \right| = n + 1$. What do we know about the periodicity of the chain and the probabilities of its transition matrix?

Comment: Your first sentence is incorrect.  A continuous-time Markov chain (CTMC) does not necessarily have an infinite state space. Also, a CTMC is not the same thing as a Poisson process. Also, there is no way to logically connect a CTMC with a Poisson process to conclude there are infinite states (so your "so that the" phrase does not make sense).

Comment: @Michael I see. How can we fix the first sentence? If we set the chain to move to a new state according to the counting measure associated to the Poisson process, then is it not true that the chain will spend an exponentially distributed time in each state, thus making it CTMC?

Comment: The only way to fix the first sentence is to completely remove it. If you want $N(t)$ to be the number of arrivals of a Poisson process during $[0,t]$, you would say "Let $N(t)$ be a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$" or "Let $N(t)$ be the number of arrivals of a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$ during $[0,t]$."

Comment: Also, the concept of "periodicity" does not make sense for CTMCs. Only for DTMCs.

Comment: @Michael Would you say that the paragraph is now better? If so, what do we know about the chain?

Comment: Yes the paragraph makes sense now. However if $X_t = N(t)$ (mod $n$) then $X_t \in \{0, 1, ..., n-1\}$. You can see everything about the chain just by drawing its picture.

Comment: @Michael What about the transition probabilities? I already tried to work out what $P(X_t = k)$ is, but I ended up with a power series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{nk}}{(nk)!}e^{-\lambda}$ and I am not sure how to simplify it.

Comment: Discrete time Markov chains (DTMCs) have transition probabilities $P_{ij}$.  Continuous time Markov chains (CTMCs) have transition rates $q_{ij}$, although you can also consider the embedded DTMC for transition probabilities.  This chain is trivial because, if you actually draw the picture, you will find every state has only one arrow out of it, so every state always goes to a single next-state. The transition rates $q_{ij}$ of the CTMC are trivial, as are the transition probabilities $P_{ij}$ of the embedded DTMC. The steady state is also trivial.